# Java: Add to Stack from Set

Tags: java, list, stack, set

The problem im having is that I am reading data from a file (fine) into the program and arranging the data into Stacks (also fine) but Im having problems as Im trying to work out how to avoid having any duplicate data enter into the stack(s).

I asked around and was recommended to use a set, which I have but I have no idea how to get data out of the set and into the stacks

```
    Stack<String> stack1 = new Stack<String>();
    Stack<String> stack2 = new Stack<String>();
    Set<String> duplicateCheck = new HashSet<String>();



    try
    {
        //Read file
        File myFile = new File("TestData.txt");
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(myFile);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        String line = null;
        int count = 0;
    while((line = br.readLine()) != null)
        {
            StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(line,",");
            while(st.hasMoreElements())
            {
                duplicateCheck.add(st.nextToken());

                if(count < 9)
                {
                    stack1???????????????;
                }
                if(count >9 && count <19)
                {
                    stack2???????????????;
                }
                if(count >= 19)
                {
                    System.out.println("Capacity has been reached");
                }
                count++;
            }
        }
```

That is the code I currently have (minus all the question marks) and if anyone could give some pointers as to where i may be going wrong, itd be much appreciated

Comment: What is your requirement for the Stack sizes (i.e why the check for the count)? You could simply fill the Set in the loop and add it to stack after the loop ends.

Answer (score 2):

The stack inherits a `contains(Object o)` function from `Vector`: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html#contains(java.lang.Object)

So, something like this should work:

```
    String currentToken = st.nextToken();
    if(count < 9) {
        if (! stack1.contains(currentToken)) { stack1.add(currentToken); }
    }
    if(count >9 && count <19) {
        if (! stack2.contains(currentToken)) { stack2.add(currentToken); }
    }
```

Or if you'd put elements to `stack2` only when the element is not in `stack1` nor `stack2` then you should rewrite the predicate in the second if statement.

Answer (score 1):

Before you go any further, is it an absolute requirement to use `Stack`? The Javadoc for this class says: "A more complete and consistent set of LIFO stack operations is provided by the Deque interface and its implementations, which should be used in preference to this class."

Furthermore, is it also a requirement to use `StringTokenizer`? The Javadoc for that class says: "StringTokenizer is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility reasons although its use is discouraged in new code. It is recommended that anyone seeking this functionality use the split method of String or the java.util.regex package instead."

Perhaps you are working from a very old book that uses an obsolete version of Java?

Now, on to your question. You can use a `Set`, as you are doing, to check for duplicates. Its [add](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#add-E-) method returns `true` if the element didn't already exist and was added in this call, or `false` if the element was not added because it already existed. Therefore, you can use the set like this:

```
String token = st.nextToken();
if (duplicateCheck.add(token)) {
    if (count < 9)
        stack1.add(token);
    else if (count < 19)
        stack2.add(token);
    else
        System.out.println("Capacity has been reached");
    count++;
}
```